# extract specific string if another string IN SAME LINE appears more than once

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I had to carefully rephrase this question :)

Need help trying to extract a string ONLY when another string (in the same line) appears twice in the file. (platform unix, can use ksh/awk/sed)
for e.g

list.txt contains:

```
Found 2 items
-rwxr-xr-x   3 xyz hdfs      21696 2018-08-06 11:57 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-12/event_hr=20/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   3 xyz hdfs      21696 2018-08-06 11:57 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-12/event_hr=23/000000_0
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 xyz hdfs      33006 2018-08-06 11:32 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-13/event_hr=01/part-00001-6c3c68ff-3792-4810-847a-1ce73d8b8a69.c000
-rw-r--r--   3 xyz hdfs      33006 2018-08-06 11:32 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-13/event_hr=01/part-00000-fb3fc3fb-4960-4674-a8e5-7c600ec43b49.c000
-rw-r--r--   3 xyz hdfs      33006 2018-08-06 11:32 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-13/event_hr=02/part-00000-fb3fc3fb-4960-4674-a8e5-6938600ec43b49.c000
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 xyz hdfs      33006 2018-08-06 11:32 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-14/event_hr=07/part-00001-6c3c68ff-3792-4810-847a-1ce7823469.c2302
-rw-r--r--   3 xyz hdfs      33006 2018-08-06 11:32 some_table/event_dt=2018-05-14/event_hr=07/part-00000-fb3fc3fb-4960-4674-9238-1239-ec43b49.c000
```

given above file,I need to extract all the event_dt="?" values and use them for further operation, whenever event_hr for that specific event_dt appears more than once. for above ,it will ignore "2018-05-12" (since all event_hr appears exactly once). 
**EDIT:I believe if there is no oneliner way to store the event_dt while scanning the file, perhaps storing the list of event_dt in another file and looping additional operations using those.

for above it will output file.

result.txt which contains:

```
2018-05-13
2018-05-14
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively store [...] in a variable"? What's the status at the end? One variable per eligible line?

Comment: @StrangerThinks Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: Apologies if I haven't been clear. 

I need to scan through the list.txt file and use the event_dt for  some operation. But only the event_dt="?" values which satisfy the above condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file only contains lines of the format you've shown, we can remove the "Found" lines, which do not have any `event_dt` / `event_hr` information with:

```
grep -v Found
```

This can then be piped into sed to extract out the `event_dt` / `event_hr` values.  Your input suggests that the different values are / separated, so:

```
sed 's/.*event_dt=\(.*\)\/event_hr=\(.*\)\/.*/\1 \2/'
```

We're then after repeated lines; i.e. ones where `event_dt` / `event_hr` both match.  You don't indicate whether your lines will be grouped or not so, just to be safe we'll run it through `sort` (to group them) then `uniq -d`

Now this will give us a list of `event_dt` / `event_hr` pairings.  Finally, we only want the `event_dt`, so we can use

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

Just in case we've still got duplicates, (e.g. an `event_dt` with multiple duplicated `event_hr` values we'll remove duplicates with `uniq`.

This gives us:

```
grep -v Found list.txt | sed 's/.*event_dt=\(.*\)\/event_hr=\(.*\)\/.*/\1 \2/' | sort | uniq -d | awk '{print $1}' | uniq
```

Comment: Excellent! :)  I was thinking of extracting only the event_dt by checking each line... turns out I was looking in the wrong way. Your approach of picking the pair makes it soo much easier to implement with uniq ! :D remarkable.... thank you for your precious time @borrible